# 404. Not Found. nginx. Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nginx

I'm new in this Kubernetes/Microservices world and I'm having this problem that I'm not able to figure out.

[image: ![enter image description here]

And these are my services up and my pods:

[image]

And finally, this is my kubernetes config file:

```
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: posts.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /posts/create
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: posts-clusterip-srv
                port:
                  number: 4000
          - path: /posts
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: query-srv
                port:
                  number: 4002
          - path: /posts/?(.*)/comments
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: comments-srv
                port:
                  number: 4001
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

Adding also services running:

[image]

Also, I have modified my hosts file so that my 127.0.0.1 points to posts.com.

If you need any other information, please do not hesitate to ask!!!!

Thank you.

Comment: So first thing that I came out with is that to use regex in your nginx file, you need this line:

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'

and this is causing me another error that I paste in the original question

Answer (score 0):

This error was caused by the environment variables declared on the Dockerfile of my client service:

```
ENV CI=true
ENV WDS_SOCKET_PORT=0
```

Cannot have blank spaces, e.g. this won't work: `ENV CI = true`